# SQL Exception while accessing CLOB

Tags: spring, hibernate, clob

I am working on application which uses Spring 3, Hibernate, oracle 10g. In db i am storing some HTML source and the type of that is CLOB. In my java code I am trying to read a CLOB as below.

```
Clob description= value.getMessage();
long lngth= description.length();
```

but at the time of length() gives me error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
```

If session getting close at this time so how can i continue with that session? My application using Hibernate Named Query and persistence.xml configuration.
So can somebody help me on this.

**Edit**

I have also tried.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
```

and

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
```

but still the same problem.

Thank You